# How to show one model in two different layouts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two layouts: `admin_layout.html.erb` and `application.html.erb`. The admin works in the `admin_layout` and creates Users. There is a `show` page for each User under the `admin_layout`.  But now I would like the general public to view a public version of each User's `show` page under the `application` layout.  Is it possible to display two different `show` actions depending on the layout or do I need to build something like a `public_users_controller`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which layout to use in your action, and you can also tell it to render a different template than the current action's name. In this example, public users would be shown the `app/views/users/public_show.html.erb` file using the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` layout.

```
def show
  if current_user.admin? # Or however you want to determine which layout to use
    render :layout => "admin_layout"
  else
    render "public_show", :layout => "application"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, that's half of it. But how do I have one show page for an admin_layout and a different show page for an application layout?